# Mounted HDD not having enough permissions from Apache/PHP

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, file-permissions

Piwigo gallery, on apache and php, CentOS 6.

The root system is a RAID 128GB. /var/www/html is on the root file system.

Mounted the 320GB hdd to /var/www/html/320 using defaults, it's an ext4 fs.

Put a symlink to it in /var/www/html/galleries which is read by the gallery script so I can upload images to there, then click sync. It gives me the error:

[./galleries/] PWG-ERROR-NO-FS (File/directory read error) PWG-ERROR-NO-FS: The file or directory cannot be accessed (either it does not exist or the access is denied)

chmod 777 set on /dev/sdb1, /var/www/html, and /var/www/html/320 as well as the symlink galleries too. All recursive.

chown apache:apache to everything too.

PHP just can't read/write to it. I tried with and without the symlink, I've tried everything I can think of. Nothing.

Any ideas how I can give apache/php permission to read/write to this drive? With 777 permissions all around it should already be able to.

Comment: Well, since you broke everything by using `chmod 777` you should probably just start over and reinstall your web app. Anyway you should check your error logs to find any actual errors.

Comment: No errors in logs and nothing is broken if the files are in ./galleries on the main hdd and not the mounted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS has a special kind of security on his kernel (SELinux), you should try disabling it first.

Check if it's enabled with this command:

```
#sestatus
```

It should show **enabled**

Disable it editing this file:

```
nano /etc/selinux/config
```

and change this:

> SELINUX=enabled

to:

> SELINUX=disabled

And try again...

Good luck...

Comment: You got it! Thanks so much. Been at it for 3 days, tried everything I could think of. Now setting everything back to the way it was before all this problem-solving.

Comment: No problem, you can also set it up to permissive and give SELinux a more personal configuration...

Comment: you could relabel the dir where the gallery is to have a proper selinux context to serve web files: (as root) chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/dir and re-enable selinux. This is a nice howto: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux